# Configuring stylelint for sass

Tags: npm, sass, yarnpkg, lint, stylelint

I'm trying to configure `stylelint` on my project for sass, and this is my `.stylelintrc`:

```yaml
defaultSeverity: warning
extends:
    - stylelint-config-standard
    - stylelint-config-recommended
    - stylelint-config-sass-guidelines
plugins:
    - stylelint-scss
```

This task is configured in my package.json as following:

```json
"lint:styles": "stylelint src/assets/sass/**/*.scss",
```

But when I run `yarn lint:styles` I get this error:

```
$ stylelint src/assets/sass/**/*.scss
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the unquoted glob.

The [stylelint documentation](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/cli#usage-examples) recommends quoting your globs, like so:

```
"lint:styles": "stylelint 'src/assets/sass/**/*.scss'",
```

Or, if you want it to work on Windows:

```
"lint:styles": "stylelint \"src/assets/sass/**/*.scss\"",
```

---

Incidentally, `stylelint-config-standard` extends `stylelint-config-recommended` so you don't need to include `stylelint-config-recommended` in your configuration.